# C# question RSS feeds broken

Tags: bug, feed

Any RSS feed readers read https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c%23 as https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c# due to the `href` tags pointing to the string "https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c#"

Is this a bug on the RSS feed readers (like [newsblur](http://newsblur.com/) and [Feedly](http://www.feedly.com/)) or incorrect meta data in the RSS feed? (I'm not an expert on RSS feed standards; that is why I'm asking)